# What is the URL of an individual answer?

Tags: support

In a comment, someone posted a URL that went directly to a particular answer to a certain question.  How does one find the URL of a particular answer?

Answer (score 6):

Look at the bottom of each post (question or answer). See the gray-text links ("edit" "flag" and "share")? Those are hot-links and "share" has the permalink address. Use your browser to copy it's URL.

For comments you can get a permalink from the time-stamp (but be aware that comments are not very permanent and can be deleted without warning).